# Issue resolving gradle dependency in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, dependencies

I am trying to add a styled progress bar from https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1375

There it says:

Add the specific repository to your build file:

```
repositories {
   maven {
      url "https://jitpack.io"
   }
}
```

Add the dependency in your build file (do not forget to specify the correct qualifier, usually 'aar'):

```
dependencies {
   compile 'com.github.akexorcist:Android-RoundCornerProgressBar:1.0.0'
}
```

Well I did that...
build.gradle (Project)

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
      url "https://jitpack.io"
   }

}
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
  }
}

allprojects {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
  }
}
```

build.gradle (Module):
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.chaz.simsirl"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
   compile 'com.github.akexorcist:Android-RoundCornerProgressBar:1.0.0'
}
```

Then in messages it says:
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
>   Could not find com.akexorcist:Android-RoundCornerProgressBar:1.0.0.
>        Searched in the following locations:
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/akexorcist/Android-RoundCornerProgressBar/1.0.0/Android-RoundCornerProgressBar-1.0.0.pom
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/akexorcist/Android-RoundCornerProgressBar/1.0.0/Android-RoundCornerProgressBar-1.0.0.jar
>            file:/C:/Users/pc/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/akexorcist/Android-RoundCornerProgressBar/1.0.0/Android-RoundCornerProgressBar-1.0.0.pom
>            file:/C:/Users/pc/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/akexorcist/Android-RoundCornerProgressBar/1.0.0/Android-RoundCornerProgressBar-1.0.0.jar
>            file:/C:/Users/pc/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/akexorcist/Android-RoundCornerProgressBar/1.0.0/Android-RoundCornerProgressBar-1.0.0.pom
>            file:/C:/Users/pc/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/akexorcist/Android-RoundCornerProgressBar/1.0.0/Android-RoundCornerProgressBar-1.0.0.jar
>        Required by:
>            SimsIRL:app:unspecified

Comment: You've placed the jitpack repository in the wrong place. It should be under allprojects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace your dependency with this:

```
compile 'com.akexorcist:RoundCornerProgressBar:1.0.0'
```

This [package](https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter/com.akexorcist%3ARoundCornerProgressBar/view) is available in jCenter.

Then you can remove this:

```
maven {
   url "https://jitpack.io"
}
```

Reference: https://github.com/akexorcist/Android-RoundCornerProgressBar#download

Comment: hey thanks! Worked like a charm. I feel silly for not picking up on that now

Comment: This only works for @pxlcrisis because they are referencing a library which also happens to have a jCenter entry. The purpose of jitpack is to cleverly allow a gradle file to reference a GitHub repository, which is a very useful way to easily compile your own GitHub fork of a library. metrimer's answer should be the accepted one (IMHO) because it addresses the actual problem the OP had, which was the fact that gradle wasn't searching the jitpack repository.

Answer (score 28):

You would need to add the jitpack repository in a different place:

```
allprojects {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
  }
}
```

Then it works

In your first snippet it was added under `buildscript` and it should be removed from there.

Comment: Immense help! Thank you.