# Android Studio - add ownCloud library from GitHub

Tags: java, android

I don't understand how to add this library (https://github.com/owncloud/android-library) to my project in Android Studio.

Comment: Did you read the installation instructions on the GitHub? Please post your attempt as well.

Comment: this library is add as a module in your android studio. and add in gridal file

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I have tried to import this library as a module but found error while importing:
Error: **Module name is not valid**

So I tried to find a solution and here it is:

**1. Download library from Github [here](https://github.com/owncloud/android-library/archive/master.zip).**

[image]

**2. Unzip library.**

**3. Start Android Studio.**

**4. Follow to File -> New -> Import Module .**

[image]

**5. Go to the path where your extracted library is located and select it.**

[image]

**6. Uncheck other modules and add *'androidlibrarymaster'* described in below picture.**

[image]

**7. Add Gradle dependency and Its Done!**

```
  compile project(':androidlibrarymaster');
```

Comment: I had also followed this way and 
I do not know if it's righ, for this i asked

Comment: @Pinco Panco : Obviously your app working with this module then its right.. :)

Comment: no, not resolve import com.owncloud.android.lib.common.network.OnDatatransferProgressListener;
 etc..

Comment: @Pinco Panco : I am able to import OwnCloudCredentials and OnDatatransferProgressListener also..!!

Comment: @Pinco Panco : Welcome.!!

Comment: you know how to check the login for client??

Comment: @Pinco Panco : I really had no idea about this library..!!

Comment: I set credential with mClient.setCredentials,how to check if you are right?

Comment: @AndiGeeky I follow your stem but i am getting . 
  Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found.
What should i do??

Comment: as of Android Studio 3.0.x the first Module Name input field is no longer available, any fix then @AndiGeeky

Answer (score 12):

Maybe try [jitpack](https://jitpack.io/) website to import this project with build.gradle file.

You have to add this snippet to your build.gradle file :

```
repositories {
    // ...
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
```

And this statement to your dependencies :

```
compile 'com.github.owncloud:android-library:oc-android-library-0.9.7'
```

Comment: I have two build.gradle , which I must change? module or project

Comment: If you not renamed your module name it should be the one in `app` folder.

Comment: Can also add it to `allprojects` as shown here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28779356/issue-resolving-gradle-dependency-in-android-studio/29565737#29565737 . just don't add it under `buildscript`

Comment: Where do you find this name: "oc-android-library-0.9.7" on github?

Comment: @Jomme In releases tab. The last part of Gradle dependency definition is version. In case of this library the versions are tagged as 'oc-android-librabry-0.9.x'.