# Unable to get the change applied in external library file

Tags: android

I have used TedBottomPicker library for image selection. Here is the link:  https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/4320  . I need to get the image selection from every folder of gallery not just from Pictures folder (as done in the source code of this library). I have downloaded the code and edited TedBottomPicker.java on line 446 as (DIRECTORY_PICTURES to DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS). which works fine when i launch the app, it selects images from every folder such as camera, whatsapp,etc.

Now problem is Once I import this library as module to my project and changed DIRECTORY_PICTURES to DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS in its source code, it will still just showing the images from Pictures folder. I follow this link to import my library: [Android studio - add library from github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32600325/android-studio-add-library-from-github) 
Tell me why my applied change in the java file is not going to show in my android project. Thanks in advance Here is code of external Library method:

```
private File getImageFile() {
    // Create an image file name
    File imageFile = null;
    try {
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);

        if (!storageDir.exists())
            storageDir.mkdirs();

        imageFile = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );


        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        cameraImageUri = Uri.fromFile(imageFile);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        errorMessage("Could not create imageFile for camera");
    }

    return imageFile;
}
```

and i have used this code in my Activity:      
        `

```
if(tempImageList.size()>0){
    //Loading with previous selection
    bottomSheetDialogFragment = new TedBottomPicker.Builder(MessagesActivity.this)
           .setOnMultiImageSelectedListener(new TedBottomPicker.OnMultiImageSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onImagesSelected(ArrayList<Uri> uriList) {
                    tempImageList = uriList;
                    for (int i = 0; i < tempImageList.size(); i++) {
                        Uri uri=tempImageList.get(i); //setting selected images in my variable
                        System.out.print("myUri"+ uri);
                    }
                }
           })
           .setPeekHeight(1000)
           .showTitle(false)
           .setCompleteButtonText("Done")
           .setEmptySelectionText("No Select")
           .setSelectedUriList(tempImageList)
           .create();
    bottomSheetDialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager());
} else {
    //Loading New 
    bottomSheetDialogFragment = new TedBottomPicker.Builder(MessagesActivity.this)
           .setOnMultiImageSelectedListener(new TedBottomPicker.OnMultiImageSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onImagesSelected(ArrayList<Uri> uriList) {
                    tempImageList=uriList;
                }
            })
            .setPeekHeight(1000)
            .showTitle(false)
            .setCompleteButtonText("Done")
            .setEmptySelectionText("No Select")
            .create();
    bottomSheetDialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager());
}
```

Comment: Post some code, it is easier to understand then

Comment: I edited my post.