# Android progressBar is not showing

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-progressbar

My custom progress bar doesn't show. I animate it in my activity and also use drawable resource file for it. Here is my code.

Activity.java

```
  ProgressBar progressBar;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
      progressBar =  findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(progressBar, "progress", 
   0, 500); 
    animation.setDuration(5000); // in milliseconds
    animation.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
    animation.start();
```

activity.xml

```
      <ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"

    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:max="500"
    android:progress="0"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circular"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/relativeLayout"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/relativeLayout"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.475"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/relativeLayout"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/relativeLayout"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.153" />
```

drawableResource.xml

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:useLevel="true"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:innerRadiusRatio="2.3"
        android:shape="ring"
        android:thickness="3.8sp" >
        <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
     </shape>
```

[want this kind of progress bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlGka.png)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why your custom one isn't working but this one works with your activity.java so your XML is definitely the problem. Here is a progress bar that does work.If you are looking to add the percentage, I suggest taking a look here:https://github.com/ylyc/circular_progress_bar.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ProgressBar android:indeterminate="true"
        android:useLevel="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/circular"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"></ProgressBar>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Hi @Kamarudeen Ayankunbi how can i add a library that you mentioned   in my android project .please elaborate ???

Comment: Try this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32600325/android-studio-add-library-from-github