# How to import a github library to androidStudio without explanation?

Tags: android, github

I am currently trying to import a library from github into my androidStudio project. Until now I had no problem with it, because there was always an exaplanation in the Readme on what exactly to include into my build.gradle. But for these libraries e.g.:

- https://github.com/kencheung4/android-StickerView
- https://github.com/nimengbo/StickerView

I have no idea how to include them in to my build.gradle to import them.

Best regards

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android studio - add library from github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32600325/android-studio-add-library-from-github)

Comment: I tried to to it like this, but when I include "compile project (':stickerview') into my build.gradle I get the error: ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :stickerview.
I called the imported module stickerview.

Comment: are you getting the error for https://github.com/nimengbo/StickerView project or both the projects?

Comment: It's the same problem for all libraries I try to include like that. If I try to use "implementatin ':stickerview' instead of the deperecated "compile", I get: 
ERROR: Failed to resolve: :stickerview:
despite that I have the module in my project.

Comment: check this you are trying to import a regular project as library project. 
Check this link: https://github.com/nimengbo/StickerView/blob/master/app/build.gradle 
The first line should be apply plugin: apply plugin: 'com.android.library' instead of 'com.android.application'

Comment: I changed the build.gradle(:stickerview) to apply plugin: 'com.android.library' and deleted the applicatinID (else it will get an error). But still when using     implementation ':stickerview' in my build.gradle(:app) I get: 
ERROR: Failed to resolve: :stickerview:

Comment: Alright it worked now using your library tip + using the deprecated compile method instead if implementatin. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome, instead of compile try using implementation project(path: ':stickerview')
replace stickerview with the name you gave to the module. So that there won't be any deprecated code in your project.